# HTML <label> with for=DIV-ID to focus a contenteditable div (does label <label> only support form elements?)

Tags: javascript, html

Given that `HTMLInputElement`, `HTMLSelectElement` and `HTMLTextAreaElement` all directly inherit `HTMLElement` (and not something common, like a HTMLFormElement), I'd expect that `<label>` would be able to focus non-field elements such as a `<div>`.

However, the code example below shows a `<label>` correctly focusing a `<textarea>`, but requires a JS hack (used jQuery in the example) to focus the contenteditable `<div>`.

Is there a published list of elements that `<label>` works with?  Or any documentation that discusses the usage of  with contenteditable `<div>`s? Am I missing something, maybe JS is not needed to focus the contenteditable `<div>`?

```
<div>
  <label for="textarea-id" style="font-weight:bold;">Label Text Area</label><br>
  <textarea id="textarea-id">
Editable text
  </textarea>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:20px">
  <label for="contenteditable-id" id="label-for-div-id" style="font-weight:bold;">Label Editable Div</label><br>
  <div id="contenteditable-id" contenteditable="true" style="border:solid 1px black">
    <p>
      <span>Edtiable text</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#label-for-div-id').on('click', function() {
    $('#' + $(this).attr('for')).focus();
  })
})
</script>
```

Posted at https://jsfiddle.net/jkvsd03y/5/

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar tabindex does NOT solve problem in [this case](https://jsfiddle.net/Lamik/mn48y2cL/2/)

Comment: ah, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<label>` elements can be associated to **labelable elements**.

From the [label Element doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label):

> **for**
>
> The `id` of a **labelable** form-related element in the same document as the  element. The first element in the document with an id matching the value of the for attribute is the labeled control for this label element, if it is a labelable element. If it is not labelable then the for attribute has no effect. If there are other elements which also match the id value, later in the document, they are not considered.

From the [Content Categories doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Form_labelable):

> **labelable**
>
> Elements that can be associated with `<label>` elements. Contains
>   `<button>`, `<input>`, `<keygen>`, `<meter>`, `<output>`, `<progress>`, `<select>`,
>   and `<textarea>`.

Comment: Thanks! Searching the web for 'html "labelable"' fills the gap!

Answer (score 4):

I was going to post about [labelable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Attributes) elements - but was late. Though, here I'm just placing for providing it full:

> **labelable**
>
> Elements that can be associated with `<label>` elements. Contains
>   `<button>`, `<input>`, `<keygen>`, `<meter>`, `<output>`, `<progress>`, `<select>`,
>   and `<textarea>`.

Note that keygen is deprecated.

What's new in my answer? Well, I did a little hack:

```html
<a href="#contenteditable-id">
  <label for="contenteditable-id" id="label-for-div-id" style="font-weight:bold;">
    Label Editable Div
  </label>
 </a>
<div id="contenteditable-id" contenteditable="true" style="border:solid 1px black">
    <p>
      <span>Edtiable text</span>
    </p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Good to see a non-JS answer to this.  I think it's worth describing that this solution works without the `<label>` element, or at least when the label element has no attributes.

Comment: Don't forget to add tabindex="-1" to the ancor tag here. Otherwise tabbing will select the link and the user has no idea why.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend using a label element. It's not valid HTML and it doesn't actually label the editable div element.

Instead, you can use an aria-labelledby attribute on the editable div element and point it to an ID on the element you use as your visible label.

In the snippet below I also simplified the focus functionality by using an old school onclick event attribute. Although the OP used jQuery, it isn't necessary here. Feel free to ignore that bit.

```css
body {
  font: 100%/1.5 sans-serif;
  color: #444;
}

.richtext {
  border: solid 1px currentColor;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1px 2px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<span id="notes-label" onclick="document.getElementById('notes-input').focus()">Notes</span>
<div id="notes-input" class="richtext" aria-labelledby="notes-label" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

with inline javascript, you can add to your label tag

```
onclick="document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('for')).focus()"
```

example :

```
<label for="courriel" onclick="document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('for')).focus()">
    <span id="courriel" contenteditable></span>
</label>
```

will have the expected behavior

Answer (score 0):

Just hook <label>'s "click" event and redirect focus to your contenteditable control.

```
$('label[for="' + hiddenControlId + '"]').on("click", function() {
    // it won't focus immediately after click, so let's focus when this thread is about to finish
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#contenteditable-id").focus(); // set input focus
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: This solution wont work after label's `for` attribute is changed